# Is something like cosmic refraction possible?

Tags: cosmology, refraction

From what I understand, these papers postulate the speed of light is dependent upon the properties of the quantum vacuum.

- [The quantum vacuum as the origin of the speed of light](https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.6165)
- [Special theory of relativity postulated on homogeneity of
  space and time and on relativity principle](http://fqxi.org/data/forum-attachments/Special_theory_of_relativity_postulated_on_homogeneity_of_space_and_time_and_on_relativity_principle.pdf)

My very naïve understanding of cosmology suggests that the properties of the quantum vacuum would have changed over time as the Universe cooled and expanded. What I'm wondering is if the light from distant stars will have passed through different state of quantum vacuum, would it have experienced a phenomenon like refraction? If so, would this affect our perception of the relative distance of objects and related phenomena (e.g. redshift, accelerated expansion)?

Finally, and this is almost certainly a bridge too far, but would dark matter necessarily have been postulated if a 'cosmic refraction' phenomena were sufficient to explain accelerated cosmic expansion?

Comment: I thought various gamma-ray-bursts have ruled out frequency-dependent refraction.